# Is it possible to map one route to a group of specific controller actions in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Let's say I have two sets of similar controller actions:

```
Photos/OriginalList/{filterBy}
Photos/PhotoShopList/{filterBy}

Photos/OriginalSingle/{id}/{filterBy}
Photos/PhotoShopSingle/{id}/{filterBy}
```

In the both groups, filterBy is optional.

Is there any way to create routes which can group similar actions together, or do I need to create explicit routes for each action?

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "FilteredPhotoList", url: "Photos/{action=*List}/{filterBy}", defaults: new {
    controller = "Photos",
    action = "OriginalList",
    filterBy = UrlParameter.Optional
}, namespaces: new string[] { "BetterExample" });

routes.MapRoute(name: "FilteredPhotoSingle", url: "Photos/{action=*Single}/{id}/{filterBy}", defaults: new {
    controller = "Photos",
    action = "OriginalSingle",
    filterBy = UrlParameter.Optional
}, namespaces: new string[] { "BetterExample" });
```

Comment: Those routes are not very RESTful. Resources should not represent verbs, they should represent nouns. You should consider a different design. FWIW, RFC 2518 does define the `MOVE` and `COPY` HTTP verbs you could use in your application, provided your web-server lets you add custom HTTP verbs.

Comment: It is just a theoretical example to illustrate the ends I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Iif you swapped `{src}` and `{dest}` then it becomes simple - only one route definition is required to handle all the urls you have shown

Comment: Apparently I'm very bad at examples.  I'm going to re-write the question to more closely match my use case.

Comment: Just change `{action=*List}` to `{action}` - i.e. `url: "Photos/{action}/{filterBy}"` and ditto for your other route

Comment: @StephenMuecke It seems if I do that, a call to Photos/OriginalSingle/{id} gets mapped to the FilteredPhotoList Route instead, which ends up interpreting the id as a filterBy argument.  I think this is due to filterBy being optional.

Comment: Yes, because the first route means match any url where the 1st segment is `Photos` and has 0, 1, or 2 additional segments. If `id` is an `int` for example, you can add a route constraint (meaning if the 3rd segment cannot be converted to an `int` it will not match and therefore use the 2nd route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define each route explicitly for better readability and code cleanliness.

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid having a long list of routes to maintain in the route config, if possible.

Comment: It seems what I was hoping for isn't quite possible, so this is probably the best approach.